# Value not setting in Backing Bean after putting render attribute

Tags: jsf-2

In the below code, the value of Price is not setting in backing bean after I set the render attribute. Prior to that It was setting into the backing Bean.

```
h:dataTable id="Table" value="#{bean.orderList}" var="attr" binding="#{bean.orderTable}">
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Item"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{attr.orderItem.itemId}" rendered="#{attr.orderItem.itemId != null}" />
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{attr.orderItem.itemId}" rendered="#{attr.orderItem.itemId == null}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.itemList}" var="attrList" itemValue="#{attrList.itemId}" itemLabel="#{attrList.itemName}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:column>

<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Price" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{attr.price}" rendered="#{attr.orderItem.itemId != null}" />
    <h:inputText value="#{attr.price}" rendered="#{attr.orderItem.itemId == null}" />
</h:column>
```

Please find below the Code for bean

```
public String addAction() {
                Order ord = new Order();
        ord.setItems(new Items());
        orderList.add(ord);
        count=count+1;
        return null;
}

@PostConstruct
public void populateForm(){

    Order ord = new Order();
        ord.setItems(new Items());
    orderList= dataDao.getOrders();
    ord.add(srcTrustScore);

}
```

Comment: Problem is not visible in code posted so far. What scope is your managed bean put in? How exactly are you preparing the `orderList` property?

Comment: Bean is in Session Scope.